# Function to move/delete files within file share in Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-storage-files

I'm not proficient in Powershell yet, so please bear with me if I use the incorrect terminology.(And please correct me if I do.)

I have installed the `Az` and `Azure.Storage` modules.

I have also connected to my account using `Connect-AZAccount` (Is this the best way? Since you need to copy the URL and login via a browser)

Then I was just trying to view the files, to test the connection. Using `Get-AzureStorageFile`

This prompts me for a sharename - I used the name of the folder under File Shares in Azure Storage Explorer. But this failed, see failure below

> cmdlet Get-AzureStorageFile at command pipeline position 1 Supply
>   values for the following parameters: (Type !? for Help.) ShareName:
>   bss get-azurestoragefile : Could not get the storage context.  Please
>   pass in a storage context or set the current storage context.

Additional information to note, I do not have access to the Account Key, only the SAS Token.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Connect-AzAccount`, you will use the `Az` module powershell [`Get-AzStorageFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefile?view=azps-1.1.0) instead of `Get-AzureStorageFile`. Before running the `Get-AzStorageFile` command, you need to pass the storage context with [`New-AzStorageContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-1.1.0) to fix the error.

Sample:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<StorageAccountKey>"
Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName "<ShareName>" -Path "<ContosoWorkingFolder>" -Context $context
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the Storage Account Key, but I do have the SAS Token. Is there a way using the SAS token instead of the Account Key?

Comment: @Darwinning Of course you can, use the command like `$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -SasToken "?sv=2018-03-28&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2019-01-18T14:28:11Z&st=2019-01-18T06:28:11Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxx"` instead of the first line of the sample in my reply.